# Disappeared non-breaking space on Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, whitespace

I seng an email which might be encoding in utf-8 from my gmail. In my gmail web UI, all the white spaces between words are shown. In my colleague's Microsoft Outlook 2010, some spaces are missing.

I see the encoding of the email. If the white space is encoded in **=C2=A0**, it doesn't show on Outlook, but it shows on gmail web UI.

I know below information:

- **=C2=A0** is a non-breaking space of uft-8 encoding.
- If my colleague copy the content and paste on notepad, the white space goes back.

My Questions are:

1. Is it a bug of MS Outlook 2010?
2. How to change my email setting to make sure all the non-breaking spaces are shown?

Answer (score 0):

> In my gmail web UI, all the white spaces between words are shown. In my colleague's Microsoft Outlook 2010, some spaces are missing.

The fact is that Outlook uses Word as email editor, not IE(web). You can read more about the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)